# Can't resolve all parameters for BreakpointsService

Tags: angular, typescript

Upgraded from Angular 5.2 to 6.0 and got the above warning

Can't resolve all parameters for BreakpointsService in node_modules/angular-breakpoints/index.js This will become an error in Angular v6.x

Comment: do you have Augury plugin installed  ?

Comment: no, i haven't. how would that help resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this library is out of date (last commit ~1.5 years ago) and not compatible to Angular versions >= 5.2. The Github repo is also marked as archived.
You might want to have a look at the [`@angular/cdk` layout module](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview), which offers similar functionality.

Example for running code in case the viewport is `Medium` or `Large`, using `@angular/cdk`:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
    constructor(public breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.breakpointObserver
            .observe([Breakpoints.Medium, Breakpoints.Large])
            .subscribe((state: BreakpointState) => {
                if (state.matches) {
                    console.log('medium or large');
                    // do sth.
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated to @angular/cdk 

how can i change below to use the @angular/cdk ?


this.breakpointsService.changes.subscribe((event: BreakpointEvent) => {

     if(event.name == "lg" || event.name == "md")
     {
         this.animation = "activate";                
     }
     else{
        this.animation = "inactive";                
     }

 })

Comment: I added a short example in my original answer.